# How to console.log the

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React component and inside of it I am fetching data from a remote API, and I want to console.log it in `useEffect`. I am trying to do it but nothing doesn't get logged into the console, why? What am I missing here? Here is the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { useLocalization } from '@progress/kendo-react-intl';
import { Card, CardHeader, Avatar, CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from '@progress/kendo-react-layout';
import { guid } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';

import { Scheduler } from './../components/Scheduler';

import { employees } from './../resources/employees';
import { images } from './../resources/images';
import { orders, ordersModelFields } from './../resources/orders';
import { teams } from './../resources/teams';

// const orderEmployees = employees.filter(employee => employee.jobTitle === 'Sales Representative');
// const initialFilterState = { };

// orderEmployees.forEach(employee => {
//     if(employee.fullName === 'Wait Peperell') {
//         initialFilterState[employee.id] = false;
//     } else {
//         initialFilterState[employee.id] = true;
//     }
// });

const Planning = () => {
    const localizationService = useLocalization();
    const [filterState, setFilterState] = React.useState(initialFilterState);
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(orders);
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = React.useState(null);


     
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://mocki.io/v1/29b83c0b-1a55-430d-a173-92b3632e04aa")
        .then(response => response.json())
            // 4. Setting *dogImage* to the image url that we received from the response above
        .then(data => setFetchedData(data))
        console.log(fetchedData)
      },[])
   
    //   console.log(fetchedData)


    const onDataChange = React.useCallback(
        ({ created, updated, deleted }) => {
            setData(old => old
                // Filter the deleted items
                .filter((item) => deleted.find(current => current[ordersModelFields.id] === item[ordersModelFields.id]) === undefined)
                // Find and replace the updated items
                .map((item) => updated.find(current => current[ordersModelFields.id] === item[ordersModelFields.id]) || item)
                // Add the newly created items and assign an `id`.
                .concat(created.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item, { [ordersModelFields.id]: guid() }))))
        },
        []
    );

    const onEmployeeClick = React.useCallback(
        (employeeId) => {
            setFilterState({
                ...filterState,
                [employeeId]: !filterState[employeeId]
            });
        },
        [filterState, setFilterState]
    );

    return (
        <div id="Planning" className="planning-page main-content">
            <div className="card-container grid">
                <h3 className="card-title">{localizationService.toLanguageString('custom.teamCalendar')}</h3>
                {

                    orderEmployees.map(employee => {
                        return (
                            <div
                                key={employee.id}
                                onClick={() => onEmployeeClick(employee.id)}
                                style={!filterState[employee.id] ? {opacity: .5} : {}}
                            >
                                <Card style={{ borderWidth: 0, cursor: 'pointer'}}>
                                    <CardHeader className="k-hbox" >
                                        <Avatar type='image' shape='circle' size={'large'} style={{
                                            borderWidth: 2,
                                            borderColor: teams.find(({teamID}) => teamID === employee.teamId).teamColor,
                                        }}>
                                            <div className="k-avatar-image" style={{
                                                backgroundImage: images[employee.imgId + employee.gender],
                                                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                                backgroundPosition: 'center center',
                                            }}
                                            />
                                        </Avatar>
                                        <div>
                                            <CardTitle style={{color: teams.find(({teamID}) => teamID === employee.teamId).teamColor}}>{employee.fullName}</CardTitle>
                                            <CardSubtitle>{employee.jobTitle}</CardSubtitle>
                                        </div>
                                    </CardHeader>
                                </Card>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
                <div className="card-component" >
                    <Scheduler
                        data={data.filter(event => filterState[event.employeeID])}
                        onDataChange={onDataChange}
                        modelFields={ordersModelFields}
                        resources={[
                            {
                                name: 'Teams',
                                data: teams,
                                field: 'teamID',
                                valueField: 'teamID',
                                textField: 'teamName',
                                colorField: 'teamColor'
                            }
                        ]}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Planning;
```

I also tried to place the console.log outside of useEffect but still, nothing gets console.logged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)  **And** this? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No, didn't answer it

Comment: Sure it does.  Look in the function you pass to `useEffect`.  There are two mistakes being made there.  (1) You're trying to read the result of the AJAX operation before that operation completes (see second linked duplicate).  (2) You're trying to read the updated state immediately after updating it (see first linked duplicate).  Move the `console.log` operation into the second `.then()` function and log `data` to the console instead of `fetchedData`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look how `useEffect` work, `setFetchedData` is async.

Create another useEffect only for console.log.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(fetchedData);
      },[fetchedData]); // Update at the first render + when fetchedData state change.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://mocki.io/v1/29b83c0b-1a55-430d-a173-92b3632e04aa")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    // 4. Setting *dogImage* to the image url that we received from the response above
    .then((data) => {
      setFetchedData(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
}, []);
```

or juste create another useEffect that listens to fetchedData change, like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(fetchedData);
}, [fetchedData]);
```

Comment: Tried both now and still, nothing gets console.loged